# How to check or confirm tensorflow.js is working with SIMD or not?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I am trying to access SIMD with tensorflow.js. I am Using pose estimation model Movenet. I want to check if my code is working with SIMD or not.
I am using chrome 107 (Updated )

Is there a way to find out the working status of SIMD in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

query tf for it...

```js
mt = await tf.env().getAsync('WASM_HAS_MULTITHREAD_SUPPORT') as boolean;
simd = await tf.env().getAsync('WASM_HAS_SIMD_SUPPORT') as boolean;
```

behind the scenes (as there is no js api to do so directly), it works by instantiating a very short (50-ish bytes) wasm bytecode sequence and
looks if it fails or not

Comment: It is using simd support but not using multi threading support. how can i use the multithreading support .

Comment: it used to be hidden behind a flag `chrome://flags#enable-webassembly-threads`, but google removed it in recent versions of chrome. so if its not auto-enabled, its because chrome doesn't like something and nothing you can do to force it. note that `tf` would not benefit from multi-threading that much anyhow (but simd matters a lot).

Comment: but still simd is not able to speed up the video inferencing .Is there any other way to speed up video inferencing.

Comment: you have to be waaay more precise than that. what's the platform, what's the model itself, what is your performance and what are you comparing it with, etc. btw, if you have gpu, in 99% you're better of using `webgl` backend.